# How to draw a polyline with many points in Google Maps ( and appear the polyine)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

Why when I want to draw a polyline using Google maps V3.0 (JavaScript API) which has many points (more than about 7 points) the ployline doesn't appear , despite when trying to draw a plolyine with a few number of points it appears ?

### edit:

code

```
var polyOptions = {strokeColor: '#FF0000',strokeOpacity: 0.6,strokeWeight: 5}
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
var path = poly.getPath();
var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        var zz=a[i].split(",");
        bar lat=zz[0];
        var lng=zz[1];

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lng),parseFloat(lat));

        var icon = customIcons["dot"];
                createMarker(i,"test routing",point,icon,2);
            path.push(point);
            poly.setMap(map);
         }
```

Comment: You should swap parseFloat(lng) and parseFloat(lat) in your code.

Comment: no no ,, it's ok like this :) just wrong names !

Comment: I tried your code with an array of 1000 points, and it worked fine.  Is it possible you are seeing some kind of memory consumption problem?  I have seen an intermittent problem with the Google Maps V3 API where (apparently) markers or polylines to fail to appear if the garbage collector runs while the map is loading.  Unfortunately I do not have code that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the code that doesn't work?

Sometimes, it helps to set the map of the polyline even after you add it in the polyline options. Try something like:

```
var mypolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  map: map,
                  path: coords,
                  strokeColor: "#787878",
                  strokeOpacity: .6,
                  strokeWeight: 3,
                  clickable: false
                });

mypolyline.setMap(map);
```

Comment: You might want to add a semicolon to the end of the first line.

Then, make variable "path" an empty array instead of getting the "poly.getPath()". So do `path = [];` Then leave everything the same and keep adding points to this array with "path.push(point)". 

Next, right before you do "poly.setMap(map)", do `poly.setPath(path)`. This should work.

Also, when you create a new LatLng coordinate, are you putting the longitude before latitude on purpose?